# Is it OK to use schema models without relationships between them using Amplify Graphql in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, schema, aws-amplify

I am currently developing a social media app where I am using AWS Amplify for the backend and DataStore to save the data to DynamoDB.

I have these two models where a user can have multiple posts:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String
  email: AWSEmail
  posts: [UserPost] @hasMany
}

type UserPost @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]){
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String
  user: User @belongsTo
  comments: [UserPostComment] @hasMany
}
```

Is this a good approach, if I fetch a User form database does it fetch the related posts as well, and if I want to create a pagination for the Posts, does this work properly.